# How to create a .pt file to be used in pyramid

Tags: pyramid

I´m following the pyramid´s tutorial. in session 08 I have to create a template (.pt file) as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Quick Tutorial: ${name}</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hi ${name}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I´m using notepad++ to make this file ... but it has not this (.pt) extension.
so I´ve tried saving this file as .html or .txt  and when I run this code:

```
from pyramid.view import view_config
# First view, available at http://localhost:6543/
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='home.pt')
def home(request):
    return {'name': 'Home View'}

# /howdy
@view_config(route_name='hello', renderer='home.pt')
def hello(request):
    return {'name': 'Hello View'}
```

the system return a "file not found"....
How can I save the file as .pt ???

Thanks for your patience...

Comment: In something like Notepad++, you should be able to just type the ".pt" as the name and it will ignore whatever extension you select below.  If not that, you can either rename it in your OS.

Comment: This works perfect. // Sometimes the obvious is the most hidden thing.

Answer (score 1):

@Vi3GameHkr provided a correct answer as a comment to the question (ie just manually change the extension when saving the file).

There is another way though...

You could save the file with html extension, and then associate html templates with pyramid_chameleon renderer. You would do this as follows;

```
import pyramid_chameleon

def main(global_config, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_chameleon')
    config.add_renderer('.html', pyramid_chameleon.zpt.renderer_factory)
```

Note that pyramid_chameleon already associates txt files with its text.render_factory (I'm not sure how that is different to the zpt.render_factory).

You could then change `renderer='home.pt'` to `renderer='home.html'`

If you were using pyramid_mako, you could do the following (it is similar, but pyramid_mako has added a 'shortcut' function);

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_mako')
    config.add_mako_renderer('.html')
```

And pyramid_jinja2 provides the same shortcut;

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
    config.add_jinja2_renderer('.html')
```